# complicated pipe chain with the HttpClient in Angular with RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I dont have a lot experience in RxJS and I want to do the following thing with a RxJS pipe in my Angular service.

I tried with the iif function but I simply have not enough experience in it.

Angular Version is: **Angular 9**
RxJS Version: **6.5.5**

check response from GET request true via HttpClient
.... true -> check if can access website via HttpClient
................ true -> set this.isOnline = true
............................ get a response from another url via HttpClient
............................ true -> set this.result = responseFromUrl
........................................ end pipe
............................ false -> throwError("cant get result")
................ false -> set this.isOnline = false
............................. end pipe
.... false -> end pipe

Comment: By `true` and `false` do you mean that we are guaranteed to get a response and proceed based on the truthiness of the response, or do you mean `true` corresponds to a response and `false` to an error?

Comment: if you make a http request you get a success response or an error response -> so error response is false and a normal response is true

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```js
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

http.get(api).pipe(
  concatMap(reponseOne => {
    return http.get(accessWebsiteApi).pipe(
      concatMap(responseTwo => {
        this.isOnline = true;
        return http.get(anotherUrl);
      }),
      catchError(errorTwo => {
        this.isOnline = false;
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  })
).subscribe(
  responseFromUrl => {
    this.result = responseFromUrl;
  },
  error => {
    console.error("cant get result");
  }
);
```

Comment: could you plese explain what your code is doing, I really want to understand rxjs